# Distribution of the minimum of the squared Euclidean norm of a $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ random variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, extreme-value, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

Suppose that $X^n := \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a sample of $n$ i.i.d $p$-dimensional points, where $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$.
What is known about the distribution of $\min_{x_i \in X^n} \|x_i\|^2_2$?

I know that $\|x_i\|^2_2$ has a non-central $\chi^2_p$ distribution but does the distribution of the *sample minimum* have a name?

Links or references to related work would be much appreciated - I'm sure this quantity must have been studied before, so at this stage I'm mainly seeking some Google traction.

Comment: If you know the distribution (e.g. non-central chi-squared), then for an i.i.d. sample the min/max can be determined like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory#Univariate_theory).